# Show text in table when records have not been submitted yet?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a table which shows results from a query.
the query have records that are submitted from a form and the user chooses the time and date it will display
the month /year.

I would like to be able that when its a specific month and no results have been enter for that month yet
to show text that no results have been enter for that yet.

for example:

No results are in yet for [month].

monthly_enter_date is the date it will show the results.

What would be the best way to do this?

```
<cfset dtToday = Now() />

<table >
<thead><th>Month</th></thead>
<cfloop query="getdates">

 <cfset timesetting = #getdates.monthly_enter_date#>
  <cfif dtToday gt timesetting>
<tbody>
 <cfoutput >
<tr>
<td><a href="cse_allusers_summary_results.cfm?month=#getdates.month#&year=#getdates.year#"> #MonthAsString(month)#  #year#</a></td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
 </cfif> 
</cfloop>

</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<cfif getdates.recordcount is 0>
static text to indicate no data
<cfelse>
all that code in your question
</cfif>
```